# ORA-00911: invalid character....why exactly is this error occuring?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
CREATE  TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  enabled Number(3)  DEFAULT 1  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (username));

INSERT INTO user_table(username,password,enabled)
VALUES ('test1','$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y', true);
INSERT INTO users(username,password,enabled)
VALUES ('test2','$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y', true);
```

**Error Message :**

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: what is the datatype of `password`?

Comment: @vkp password is varchar type !

Comment: What is the data type of `enabled`? :D

Comment: It working here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23947. I kept the datatype of `enabled` as `char(1)`

Comment: man...enabled is number type

Comment: and yeah I changed that true to 1 now......it says invalid character now

Comment: How and where are you running these statements? I suspect you are trying to run all three as a single statement (e.g. select all, run statement in SQL Developer) rather than as a script, which would give this error from the semicolons. You can't run all three from a single JDBC prepared statement, for instance.

Comment: @AlexPoole no I aint doing it....all separately

Comment: Even run seperately, how are you runing them? The SQL Fiddle shows they are valid statements, so whatever client or tool you are using doesn't seem to like the semicolon statement separator. Show exactly what you are doing, and the full error message stack you get.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not support `boolean` type.

So, instead of [true] for `enabled` field, you probably should use 'true' or 1.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a46f0)

Comment: Are you sure about the datatype of `enabled` column

Comment: @Fireblade you are right....I was using mysql syntax and migrated it to oracle and just completely missed that one :p

Comment: @ArshalJain - Its not Fireblade, Its Grisha who answered :D

Comment: @ArshalJain - You put 1 for enabled and got the same error ?